# How to use select with a parameter in SQL

Tags: sql, database, select, parameters, procedure

I am trying to select `@max_disease_name` parameter (which I returned from a procedure)  as a column name:

```
select  
    Customer_id, Age 
from 
    [INPUT_DATA ] 
where 
    Gender ='Female' and @max_disease_name = 'Yes' 
order by 
    age asc
```

However, seems like SQL can't find the matched column as if the column name doesn't even exist.

It does work however when I hard code the name of the column: "HighBlood" like this:

```
select  
    Customer_id, Age 
from 
    [INPUT_DATA ]  
where 
    Gender ='Female' and
    HighBlood = 'yes'
order by 
    age asc
```

Any suggestion on how I can make it work without hard coding 'HighBlood'?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that a parameter can replace a *constant* in a query.  It cannot replace any of the following:

- A column name.
- A table name.
- A column or table alias.
- A function name.
- An operator.
- A SQL keyword.

To do what you want, you need to use *dynamic* SQL.  That is, construct the SQL as a string and then execute the SQL.  This can be handled in an application language such as Python or R, or often in the scripting language of the database.

The exact syntax varies among databases.  As pseudo-code, it looks something like:

```
set @sql = '
select  Customer_id, Age 
from [INPUT_DATA ] 
where  Gender ='Female' and @max_disease_name = 'Yes' 
orderby  age asc';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@max_disease_name', @max_disease_name);

execute @sql;
```

Two important notes:

- The syntax will vary depending on the database.
- The code is subject to SQL injection attacks, so you need to be quite careful when using dynamic SQL that munges the query string.